# Orienting planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory

What is the minimal $d\in \mathbb N$ for which every simple finite [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) can be oriented in such a way that the *out degree* (i.e. the number of edges leaving a vertex) of every vertex is $\leq d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the handshaking lemma on directed graphs, and the fact that the graph is planar, it should  be clear that $d$ must be at least $3$.

To see the opposite, use a well known fact that planar graphs have arboricity at most $3$. That means we can decompose the planar graph into at most three edge-disjoint forests. Each forest can be oriented to add at most one outgoing arc to each vertex, so we can orient the edges so that each vertex has outdegree at most $3$.